# Selecting regression model for a non-negative integer response

Tags: regression, model-selection, poisson-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution

I have a series of non-negative integers $y=(y_1,y_2,..., y_n)$ and a design matrix $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_3 x_1 x_2$, where $x_0$ and $x_1$ are $0$ or $1$, $x_1x_2$ is the interaction, and $\beta_0 \ldots \beta_3$ are parameters we want to estimate. For example, the data look like

```
y    x1    x2    x1*x2
10   0     0     0
23   0     1     0
18   1     1     1
19   1     0     0
25   0     1     0
...
```

I want to estimate the $\beta_0$, $\beta_1$, $\beta_2$ and $\beta_3$ coefficients and perform a test to see if any coefficient is nonzero.

**There are several different regression models** that might be applied to this case:

1. Simple linear regression: `lm`
2. Poisson regression (when $y$ follows a Poisson distribution): `glm` with family = poisson
3. Quasi-poisson regression (when $y$ is over-dispersed; that means $\text{sd}(y) \gt \text{mean}(y)$): `glm` with family = quasi-poisson
4. Negative binomial regression (when $y$ is over-dispersed, $\text{sd}(y) \gt \text{mean}(y)$): `glm.nb`, in MASS package.

**The questions I want to ask are:**

1. How should I select the model for this dataset? Is there any way to choose the right model based on some descriptive statistics of my dataset?
2. How should I check and validate if the fitted selected model is right for my data?

Comment: Could you specify what kind of outcome ($y$) you are studying? It might further help to decide among the various modeling strategies you proposed, or suggest other ones.

Comment: It looks like you're overthinking this one.

You have only four distinct categories, corresponding to $(x_1,x_2) \in \{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\}$.  Allowing four parameters is tantamount to fitting the $y$'s separately in each category.  Therefore you really have four independent problems and each of them reduces to summarizing a univariate dataset.

Where to go from here depends on the nature of the $y$'s and the purpose of the model, neither of which is apparent in the question.

Comment: Use a random forest?

Answer (score 1):

Your model is fully saturated, because you have indicators for every possible combination of categories. As such you have correctly specified the conditional expectation.

Any MLE estimate based on a distribution in the linear exponential family is consistent when the conditional expectation is correctly specified. Therefore you can use Poisson or a number of other distributions.

As whuber implies though, this problem reduces to estimating means and testing for their differences, which could conveniently be done in a regression framework.